# first and last rows /first and last columns of multiple data ranges in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to write a simple code that would identify first row, last row, first column and last column of individual block of data.

I have multiple blocks of data in the worksheet which is in the form of template but are dynamic and the rows in the block of data may keep on changing every time (or reporting period).

> The first block of data is ranged B2:E10
>   The second block of data is ranged B13:F29
>   The third block of data is ranged B32:H35

I wrote the following code to test if I could select the range of data from particular cell to last row and last column of the first data block, but it selected the whole data `(B2:I35)`.

```
Private Sub RangeIdentification()

 Dim Dsheet As Worksheet
 Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
 Dim firstrow1 As Long, firstrow2 As Long, firstrow3 As Long
 Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow3 As Long
 Dim lastcol1 As Long, endcol2 As Long, finalcol3 As Long

 Set Dsheet = Worksheets("Data")

 lastrow1 = Dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
 lastcol1 = Dsheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Set rng1 = Dsheet.Cells(2, 2).Resize(lastrow1 - 1, lastcol1)
 rng1.Select

End Sub
```

I would want to select `B2:E10` and then `B13:F29` and finally `B32:I35`.

Answer (score 0):

May try like this, all the Data blocks at column B will be selected (excluding Empty spaces between)

```
Sub test()
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet, Rng As Range, NextRow As Long
Dim TRng As Range
Set Dsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Set Rng = Dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).CurrentRegion
Set TRng = Rng
    Do
    NextRow = Rng(1, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If NextRow = 1 Then Exit Do
    Set Rng = Dsheet.Cells(NextRow, "B").CurrentRegion
    Set TRng = Union(TRng, Rng)
    Loop

If Not TRng Is Nothing Then TRng.Select
End Sub
```